# TWS API ib insync Bracket Order Delay for 35+ sec after Submitted

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers, tws

I got a bracket order using ib_insync.
But for whatever reason, when the orders are submitted to TWS, only the parent order will show up with "Transmit" button beside it as shown in the screen shoot below.
It then does nothing for 35+ sec. Then the entire bracket orders are sent out.
[image]

Here are my code for the bracket order:

```
    bracket = ib_val.bracketOrder("BUY", 4, current_price, current_price + 1, current_price - 3)
    bracket.parent.orderType = "MKT"
    for each_order in bracket:
        orderTrade = ib_val.placeOrder(contract_val, each_order)
        orderTrade.orderStatus.status = "Submitted"
```

Did I screwed up something?
Where is the code going wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by adding a time.sleep(1) after the bracket order.